# Find the intersection between my robot model and a line

Tags: urdf, pr2, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a given line and I know this lines intersects the PR2.
The line always intersects the robot at the same link (forearm).

I want to know WHERE this line intersects the PR2.

What is a good approach to do that?

Is there for a example a method which gives me the triangles for a link?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10443/find-the-intersection-between-my-robot-model-and-a-line/) by [Adrian](https://answers.ros.org/users/771/adrian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is code in the motion_planning_common stack which does this. Have a look at the robot_self_filter package. It contains a "shadow filter" which can detect if a sensor ray is occluded by the links of a robot - afaik it performs raycasting and detects the intersection with the mesh model, which is what you would need.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1